# After closing the app it is launching 2nd activity automatically?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have prepared one application.My application contains no.of activities.Suppose i navigate 1st activity to 2nd activity and come back to 1st screen and close the application.After closing the app it is launching 2nd activity automatically.To over come this problem i used `finish()` in `onPause()`.but it is not working.

Please let me know how to over come this problem.

```
public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        this.finish();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    }
```

Comment: post some code as how are you closing your application....

Comment: onPause is in which activity?

Comment: how you navigate from 2nd activity to 1st?

Answer (score 0):

**finish()** will just close the current Activity which is on the top of the **Stack Task** and after that the next Activity will come to the top so it runs the Activity which is on the top of current **Stack Task**.

Comment: suppose i navigate 1---->2----->3 now i am in 3 activity .when i click on back button 3---->2(click on back button)--->1(click on back button) app is closing.But again 2nd activity is opening automatically with out calling any intent.

Comment: @Chiru Sorry chiru I don't think it is an usual behavior in Android.I dont have any idea regarding that. SORRY...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

start your 2nd activity from 1st using

```
int k=1;
Intent i=new Intent(yourfirstActivity.this,second.class);
            startActivityForResult(i,k);
```

now in second activity.. close(finish) the activity like this..

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
    finish();
```

in first activity put this onactivityresult code..

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if (requestCode ==1) {
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

              this.finish();

          }
       }
    }
```

this closes both your activities once...

Comment: after adding ur code ,suppose i navigate 1---->2----->3 now i am in 3 activity .when i click on back button app is closing.But again 2nd activity is opening automatically with out calling any intent.

Comment: when you click on back button.. the app will never close.. the  activity in which you are is removed from the stack.. and you will come to the activity in which you were previously... so in ordre to close your application on clicking back button.. you need to override onclick of backbutton..

Comment: i have override onKeyDown method also and in side the method i just call finish also

Comment: you mean app is closing and again restarting with second activity?

Comment: you are calling finish in 3rd activity na... it just closes the 3rd activity.. and not the entite application.. to close the entire application... start 3rd activity from 2nd activity using startactivity for result..and same as i told in the answer.. that works for me.. :S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9086/discussion-between-chiru-and-raju)